# How to make an app to auto-click online memory game dots according to given IDs?

Tags: windows, game-physics, game-engine, game-development

So if you have an online game with some dots and every dot has some id for example you need to click the first one, the the fourth one, then second one and lastly the third one but each of these dots is separated in area and it takes time to get to them with mouse because you need to read your task for example you need to click third one, and then after you read you need to find it among those four, obviously you need to remember which one is which. And it takes some time so i am not able to get near perfect results. Is it possible to make an app like autoclicker so the computer will know which dot has which "id" and when the game asks for specific id, that app reads it and immediately clicks the right dot.

I didnt try anything because i dont know if its possible so i am asking cleverer heads than myself.

Comment: sorry but your question needs to include your code. It's not really clear what your coding problem is either. You need a bot that can play an online game?